# How to solve the error .net framework version were not found?

Tags: .net

I am getting the below error.

Error in written: `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/var/www/html/****/Sample.vbproj]`

`The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.`

Detail: I am getting this error when I am running the command `dotnet run`.

FYI, I have set up the dotnet core 3.1 on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

I am following the below documentation for that.

Dotnet setup is completed as there is Hello World small program works perfectly.

Can you do some help with this issue?

Comment: "I have set up the dotnet core 3.1" yet you target your application to dot net framework. Change the build target to dot net core 3.1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the comment. How can I change the build target to dot net core 3.1?

Comment: @ZoharPeled. I am net as the dotnet. I am founding the `TargetFrameworkVersion` tag in the Sample.vbproj file. So I am changing here. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @ZoharPeled, After the changing the version, now error is changed to like `error NU1202: Package sautinsoft.pdffocus 7.7.7.24 is not compatible with net31 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.1). Package sautinsoft.pdffocus 7.7.7.24 supports: /var/www/html/pdf_focus/Code samples/VB.Net/PDF to HTML/Convert PDF file to HTML file/Sample.vbproj : error NU1202:   - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)....
`

Comment: Do you have idea or any command to upgrade or install dotnet from 3.1 to 4.0 in ubuntu 18.04 via ssh?

Comment: No, never worked with ubuntu. Seems like you need to upgrade the incompatible nuget package

Comment: delete and reinstall your nuget packages again without specifying versions.